# How to resolve invalid object name in Stored procedure script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure to query all the records from a table named `EscalationStatus`.

But on execute of the sql script in Sql Server 2014 Management Studio ,  an error is thrown where I declare the procedure name -

```
"Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure GET_STATUS, Line 19
Invalid object name 'dbo.GET_STATUS'."
```

I checked the following that the procedure name matched the name of the sql script, and that the DB name is valid which they are.

I also took the step of "Refreshing Intellisense cache" which didn't clear out the error.

**Question:**
Does anyone know why the Procedure name is evaluated as an *invalid object name*?

The table name is `EscalationStatus`:
[image: tables]

```
`GET_STATUS` stored procedure:

USE [NOTIFICATION]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GET_STATUS]    Script Date: 12/05/2016 11:50:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_STATUS]
AS 

   BEGIN     

SELECT 
      [EscStatus]
      ,[Color]
  FROM NOTIFICATION.dbo.EscalationStatus

   END
```

Comment: Does the SP actually exist yet? I.e. have you tried replacing `ALTER` with `CREATE`?

Comment: Also what is SQL Server 2013?

Comment: If you are creating a new Stored procedure then pl use CREATE instead of ALTER. (CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_STATUS] ...)

Comment: You're trying to ALTER a procedure that has not been created.

Comment: Replacing CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_STATUS] solved it..feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: I hadn't already created the stored procedure pointed out above, so calling CREATE instead of ALTER solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the following line from the Alter procedure script or comment it out at the very first line in the above query.:

```
 `GET_STATUS` stored procedure:
```

Use this:

```
--`GET_STATUS` stored procedure:

USE [NOTIFICATION]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GET_STATUS]    Script Date: 12/05/2016 11:50:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_STATUS]
AS 

   BEGIN     

SELECT 
      [EscStatus]
      ,[Color]
  FROM NOTIFICATION.dbo.EscalationStatus

   END
```

Comment: `GET_STATUS` stored procedure: this line will defiantly will cause issues.

Comment: I can see some serial downvotes here :( I did smtg different, because your answer looks correct :) Well, you could add some words about `create` or `alter`.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this template to CREATE/ALTER procedure

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[P1]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[P1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE proc [dbo].[P1]
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 AS VAL
END

GO
```